# parsing file and appending string python

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, split, element

Let's say I have a file:

```
This is the first line
Ages = ["young*","old*"] //This was the second line, I put a * on purpose
This is the third line
```

The scenario is as:

1. I know there is the "Ages" array inside the file, but I don't have any idea about its elements.
2. I now want to append a specific string, say "test*" after each element, the file would become:

```
This is the first line
Ages = ["young\*test\*","old\*test\*"] //This was the second line, I put a * on purpose
This is the third line
```

Any help?

Comment: 1) Read the file. 2) Find that line. 3) Parse the list literal using `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads`. 4) Modify the list. 5) Put it back together into a string. 6) Write it all back out to the file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open the file with read and write mode and read it all to a string, then I think your best bet would be to use regular expressions to group what you want to replace and replace it. Then write it back to the file. It would be something similar to below:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'') # this would be your pattern
with open("filename.txt", "r+") as file:
    content = file.read() #all the content as string
    replaced = pattern.sub('the match group with your addition', content)
    file.seek(0) #the seek is necessary to return back to the start of the file
    file.write(replaced) # write the modified content to the file
    file.truncate() # truncate if there are any trailing parts from before
```

I think this is a homework so I won't complete the regular expression pattern there but I will give a hint:

Ages with trailing 0 or more spaces = with trailing 0 or more spaces array open character with a match group for your inner array elements, and another inner group that signifies the end of each element, then you can replace it accordingly.